# Make a Facebook style profile picture with divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

just yesterday i created a plan for my new profile page i'm designing. The plan will be shown below. Basically i would like to know how to get the profile picture image to float above the cover photo and the div #background. My only way two ways i would know of are: `#profile_pic {z-index:1500; }` or `#profile_pic {position:absolute;}`. If any of these would work how can i float them between the two divs. Thankyou

profile page plan:

[image: http://s10.postimg.org/8rlvj7n6x/Profile_page_plan_Myi_World.jpg]

Comment: You could put the profile picture `img` inside the cover photo div area. If you add `position:relative` to the cover photo div, you can then position the thumb `relative` to that `div` using `position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;` for example.

Comment: We're more about helping you fix your broken code, than us writing your code as per your specs.  In other words, show your honest attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: Thank you both of you and sparky, alas i did try to build this but it didn't work. Rather than trying to fix code that seemed somewhat pathetic to some i received, i decided to ask for help and used the results i gathered from this to compare with my code so i now know how to, in future, correct my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/hzJvQ/
full Screen: http://jsfiddle.net/hzJvQ/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://hdwallcomp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Fantasy-Landscape-Wallpaper-Full-HD.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
        <img src="http://malvorlagen-fensterbilder.de/bilder-bunt/Micky-Maus.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.cover {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:437px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
.cover img {
    max-width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
.profile {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border:#d0efff solid 3px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin: -100px 0 10px 20px;
    z-index:999;
}
.profile img {
    max-width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help here Mayank Tripathi, not only was it perfectly what i needed, the example just topped it off to show the results in action. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
#profile_pic {
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
    left:100px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the comment @APAD1, short, brief and exactly to the point, its great how such little code can do something like i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "easy" or default way to float it **between** the 2 divs.  That is, you simply need to calculate the height of your profile pic and then adjust it accordingly.

So, you could do it using **absolute positioning**, with a combination of `z-index` and `position:absolute` as you've mentioned... or you could use **relative positioning** and shift the profile pic half of its height down.

```
 #profile_pic {
   position: absolute;
   height: 200px;  /* it looks like this is your height */
   width: 200px;   /* it looks like this is your height */
   top: 250px;     /* it looks like this is your distance from the top */
   left: 50px;     /* it looks like this is your distance from the left */
   z-index: 99; 
 }
```

OR use relative positioning (NOTE:  you must wrap ALL your other divs inside a outside container that uses something other than the default (static) positioning, e.g.:

```
 #div_container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }  

 #profile_pic {
   position: relative;
   height: 200px;  /* it looks like this is your height */
   width: 200px;   /* it looks like this is your height */
   top: -100px;    /* shift the profile pic up half it's height */
   left: 50px;     /* it looks like this is your distance from the left  */
   z-index: 99; 
 }

 /* Now, shift the information div up 200px (the height of #profile_pic), 
 *  in order to align to the bottom of the "cover photo" div 
 */
 #information_section {
   position: relative;
   top: -100px;    
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou flak for the answer you gave, this code that you gave can be used later on in my projects as you went into much detail on the code, thankyou for your help and if i could give out reputation i would do.